# onOptionsItemSelected does not get the updated variables

Tags: android, listener

I'm not expert in Android, so sorry if my problem seems basic. I spent all last night looking it up and couldn't find a solution.

Basically, when I press a button that I have in the menu, the onOptionsItemSelected method is called to create a socket with a server. However, the IP and port necessary to create it have the initial values (null and zero).

For that reason, I tried using `SharedPreferences` to save the `remotePort` as the following code:

```
public class PlayActivity 
{
    private static final String TAG = "PlayActivity";
    private SocketClient thread;
    private WebsocketPortClient websocketClient;
    private static String remoteIP;
    private static int remotePort;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play_main);

        //request port
        context = this;
        websocketClient = new WebsocketPortClient(event.getID(), event.getTitle(), app.getMyCode());
        initWebsocketClient();
        ...
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.userComment:
                ...
                break;
            case R.id.userCamera: // Camera Button
                if (flPreview.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    ...
                } else {
                    // Here I Get the IP and Port
                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string
                            .preference_file_key),
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    remoteIP = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.ip), "192.168.1.160");
                    remotePort = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.port), 8880);

                    Log.e(TAG, "Connecting to the server: " + remoteIP + " on port: " + remotePort);
                    if (started) {
                        if (remoteIP == null) {
                            thread = new SocketClient(preview);
                        } else {
                            thread = new SocketClient(preview, remoteIP, remotePort);
                        }
                        started = false;
                        flPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        cameraOnBtn.setIcon(R.drawable.act_user_camera_ov);
                    } else {
                        closeSocketClient();
                        reset();
                    }
                }

                break;
            case android.R.id.home:
                askFinish();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void initWebsocketClient()
    {
        assigned = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        websocketClient.setListener(new WebsocketPortClient.WebsocketPortListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPortAssigned(int port)
            {
                if (portRequester.isPortReceived()) {
                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string
                            .preference_file_key),
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.port), portRequester.getAssignedPort());
                    editor.commit();

                    Log.e(TAG, "onPortAssigned: " + sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.port),
                            8880));

                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                    assigned.set(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, I tried with `AtomicInteger` for the `remotePort` but it has the same results. The value is always zero. Now using `SharedPreferences` the value I got is the previous stored value, as you can see in this log:

```
E/socketPort: connect(): ws://portassigner.net:8080/ControllerServer/actions
E/socketPort: jsonObj sent: {"action":"add","eventID":"542398d26b980","eventTitle":"테트","userID":"6da557b7d92"}
E/socketPort: jsonObj received: {"action":"add","id":0,"eventID":"542398d26b980","eventTitle":"테트","userID":"6da557b7d92","status":"Off","color":"color02","assignedPort":8680}
E/socketPort: Action: add
E/socketPort: Add Port: 8680
E/tya: Running: 4, Top: ComponentInfo{kseek.stime/kseek.stime.event.play.PlayActivity}
E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
E/tya: EventLoadingActivity::Finish()
E/tya: GC_RECV << SC;I;542398d26b980:110:1/0/1/20000;    :
E/PlayActivity: Connecting to the server: 192.168.1.160 on port: 8330
E/socket: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.160 (port 8330) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I really want to know how to update the `remotePort` value inside of the onOptionsItemSelected. The port is updated using a listener that is created when the Activity is created.
Thanks guys for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you ever set the remotePort or remoteIP? I see you are reading it but never writing to it. It will have the default value if you never set it to anything in the first place.

Comment: first I set them in the `onCreate()` when the Activity is created then because I need to update the port I create a listener. 
My log shows that the port is updated and saved in the `sharedPref`. But when I try to read it I got another port number, probably from the precious execution.

[This is the Log](http://i.imgur.com/kHWo3bD.png) <--

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `apply()` or `commit()` once you update the SharedPreferences?

Comment: Did you check my code?, in `initWebsocketClient()` I did it:
`editor.clear();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.port), portRequester.getAssignedPort());
editor.commit();`

Comment: Sorry I skipped over that part...

Answer (score 0):

**What you should do ?**

*SET the value of remoteIP in your shared preferences* after you know  the value. You have not set the value of it anywhere in the code. But you read it

**Why ?**

You have not set the value of

remoteIP anywhere in the code.

That is why

remoteIP = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.ip), "192.168.1.160");

doesn't have your IP.

You get your default port value because

if (remoteIP == null) is always true.

Comment: if you see initWebsocketClient set the value remoteIP is not the problem remotePort is my problem.. I need to update the port all the time.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to keep the port and ip variables inside the activity in a global context. Reading and writing in shared preferences seems to be consuming time and also is unnecessary in your case.

Comment: As you can see the variables are global and not only that I make then static `private static String remoteIP; private static int remotePort;`. I also try with `AtomicInteger`

Comment: Can you try this.remotePort = port; instead of the shared preferences concept ?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I did. I tried many things, nothings works